# What is the length of an array?

Tags: c, arrays

What does length mean exactly in this sentence: "Each array is passed to the function along with the “length” of that array."

Does it mean the size of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, just because you have a pointer to an array, doesn't mean you know its length (how many entries it has).  Somehow you must know to avoid array indexing errors.

There are only a small number of ways to do this:

- Agree on an array length.  The code just knows certain arrays have a certain length, e.g., 17.  This is generally considered bad practice, but people do it for arrays that are problem-domain specific such as translation matrices for 3D graphics, which tend to have 4 rows.
- Document the array length with a constant declaration or a macro definition, and use that symbol to control loops accessing the array.
- Implicitly associate a well-known variable containing the runtime array size with the array. The program consults the variable when it needs to know the array size.
- Pass the pointer to the array, and the length known *by the caller* to the callee. Now the callee knows the length, and can in turn pass it to whoever the callee calls.
- Package the array and its length in a struct, and pass a pointer to the struct.  Now the callee can consult the struct to determine the array size.

This discussion is a little confusing for the C language, because we tend in general conversation to treat array length and array size as being synonyms.  But in C, "size" has a specific meaning; it is the number of storage units occupied by an entity. It is easily computed from an array length, and sometimes programs will pass "size" rather than length.  IMHO you should pass array *lengths* to functions that manipulate arrays by indexing them, as length is more abstract and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. The **size** of the array is the **number of bytes** located for it (or at least that what `sizeof(array)` will return if it knows how many elements are there in the array) the **length** of the array is the **number of elements** in the array.

For example: `short arr[10];` its length is 10, but its size is 20 (each short is two bytes)